# Accessing a particular value in a row in CSV File using another row - python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have a CSV file where I have 3 columns. I need to access the 3rd column with respect to the values in the 1st and 2nd columns.

For Example:

```
Age |  Height (cm) | Name 
______________________________
25  |   180        |  John 
25  |   175        |  Sam 
26  |   180        |  Ben
```

Let's say I need to access only some particular names in the long list based on their age and height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check with `.loc`

```
print(df.loc[df['Age'].eq(25) & df['Height'].eq(180), 'Name'])
```